# GetSafeHtmlFragment adds a div tag after an input - Why?

Tags: asp.net, xss, antixsslibrary

```
Microsoft.Security.Application.Santizier.GetSafeHtmlFragment("<input type=""text"" />")
```

returns

```
<input type="text" /> <div></div>
```

I assume this is some sort of security feature - why does it do this?

Comment: Actually, it's more of an unintended bug. I'll put it on the list :)

Comment: Here I was, giving you the benefit of the doubt, and considering this a 'feature' and it's actually a bug. ;)

Comment: I went ahead an added the bug because I didn't see it on http://wpl.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic.

Comment: Heh, ok. I'll add it internally.

Answer (score 1):

This is reported as a bug here: http://wpl.codeplex.com/workitem/15926